# compare 2 array contents in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a 2 arrays from 2 different locations, but they contain the same elements. Below shows what I have:

```
@var2 =  ["2/05/2008", "$1.5000", "$2.0000"]
         ["1/06/2007", "$1.4000", "$1.0000"] 

@var3 =  ["1/06/2007", "$1.4000", "$1.0000"]
         ["2/05/2008", "$1.5000", "$2.0000"]
```

And this is the code how I arrive at those arrays above..not a good ruby code I acknowledge it

```
 var1 = Nokogiri::HTML(open(file.htm))
 var1.xpath('//tr[position() > 1]').map do |row|
 @var2 = row.xpath('td').map(&:text)[0,3]
    puts @var2
 end

File.open('some.txt') do |file|
  file.each_line do |line|
    line1 = line.split(' ')
    line2 = line1[0]
    line3 = "$" + line1[1]
    line4 = "$" + line1[2]

    @var3 = line2.split(' ') + line3.split(' ') + line4.split(' ')
    puts @var3
  end
  file.close()
end
```

In both of these variables I have multiple rows like this. How can I compare `@var2` and `@var3`? Also `@var2` is in descending order of date. Is there a way to compare the values/contents of the two and get a result? This also means that with the above format if I change a value in one of the arrays then the comparison should fail, for example:

```
@var2 =  ["2/05/2008", "$1.5000", "$2.0000"]
         ["1/06/2007", "$1.4000", "$1.0000"]

@var3 =  ["1/06/2007", "$1.4456", "$1.0000"]
         ["2/05/2008", "$1.5000", "$2.2222"]
```

I have tried several ways but unfortunately its not worked. I think I need to loop into the arrays and compare, but not sure how to do it.

I have tried `@var2 & @var3`, `@var2 - @var3`. They don't seem to work if I change a value in one of the arrays. The comparison still seems to check for the index and says matches is found. I want a exact row by row comparison with the values in each array.

Also further information : -

I want to know if the array contains the exact same elements, the order doesn't matter.

There can be duplicates within both the arrays var2 and var3. The array sizes will be the same. there won't be less elements nor NIL's.

Comment: Half of your data given isn't in any variables, I assume they were meant to be nested arrays?

Comment: Also, your question is very unclear: do you want to know if the arrays contain the exact same elements, regardless of order? Or does order matter? Are all the elements unique?

Comment: @Andrew, yes sorry they are nested arrays. and want to know if the array contains the exact same elements, the order doesn't matter.

Comment: So edit your question to make them correct!

Answer (score 2):

Sort the arrays before you compare them:

```
@var2.sort == @var3.sort
```

Unless I'm missing something, this is basically what the problem is.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I have updated the original question. Please have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Compare their lengths with the length of their [intersection](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-26):

```
@var2.length == @var3.length && @var2.length == (@var2 & @var3).length
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Marc-AndréLafortune! Been coding for far too many hours straight and it's far too late and I thus I end up making silly mistakes like that `:)`.

Comment: Note that the solution assumes there are no duplicates.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I think its going no where so here is the entire code and what I am doing. This aint great ruby code and I acknowledge it

Comment: `var1 = Nokogiri::HTML(open('file.html))
  var1.xpath('//tr[position() > 1]').map do |row|
    @var2 = row.xpath('td').map(&:text)[0,3]
    puts @var2.size
  end

  File.open('price.txt') do |file|
    file.each_line do |line|
      line1 = line.split(' ')
      line2 = line1[0]
      line3 = "$" + line1[1]
      line4 = "$" + line1[2]

      @var3 = line2.split(' ') + line3.split(' ') + line4.split(' ')
      puts @var3.size
    end
    file.close()
  end`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
@var2.reverse == @var3
```

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work mate. I want something where I'd be able to compare each and every value in the array "@var2 to @var3". So for example if I change a value in "@var3" from ["2/05/2008", "$1.5000", "$2.0000"] to ["2/05/2008", "$1.5000", "$2.22222"], then the comparison to "@var2" should be false and error out. Hope that helps

Comment: I want something where I'd be able to loop thru the values of the arrays

Comment: Did you try the code? It should compare every element of the array, and return false even if one thing doesn't match.

Comment: yep, and this is a smimple comparison I have

Comment: @user1126946 Can you post the code you used? That would clear things up.

Comment: 0.upto(@var2.size) do
    @var2.each do |item|
      if @var2[item] == @var3[item]
        puts "matches"
      else
        puts "no matches"
      end
    end
  end

Comment: if "@var2".reverse == "@var3"
  puts "matches"
else
  puts "no matches"
end

Comment: disregard the below piece of code please, pasted wrong and unfinished code                 

0.upto(@var2.size) do 
@var2.each do |item| 
  if @var2[item] == @var3[item] 
    puts "matches" 
  else 
    puts "no matches" 
  end 
 end 
end

Answer (score 0):

> Using `-` operator of `Array` class

```
2.1.1 :006 > arr1 = [1,2,3,4]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
2.1.1 :007 > arr2 = [4,3,2,1]
=> [4, 3, 2, 1]
2.1.1 :008 > arr1-arr2
=> []
2.1.1 :009 >
```

So, you can do it like this

```
2.1.1 :001 > @var2 =  [["2/05/2008", "$1.5000", "$2.0000"],
2.1.1 :002 >              ["1/06/2007", "$1.4000", "$1.0000"] ]
 => [["2/05/2008", "$1.5000", "$2.0000"], ["1/06/2007", "$1.4000", "$1.0000"]] 
2.1.1 :003 > 
2.1.1 :004 >   @var3 =  [["1/06/2007", "$1.4000", "$1.0000"],
2.1.1 :005 >              ["2/05/2008", "$1.5000", "$2.0000"]]
 => [["1/06/2007", "$1.4000", "$1.0000"], ["2/05/2008", "$1.5000", "$2.0000"]] 
2.1.1 :006 > (@var2 - @var3) == []
 => true
2.1.1 :007 >
```